# Javascript Interval not working

Tags: javascript

I  got 2 function in my javascript interval:
I start the interval with 2 html buttons, start (starts it) and stop (stops it)

This is started:

```
function start_sync(){
    //runs the interval
    if(sync_interval == false)
    {
        sync_interval = setInterval(function(){
            gl_context.drawImage(gl_video,0,0,gl_cw,gl_ch);
            update_seek_slider_position(gl_video.currentTime);
        },10);
        sync_interval_running = true;
    };
    console.log("Sync Interval Started");
};
```

This is called when I press stop:

```
function stop_sync(){
    if(sync_interval == true)
    {
        clearInterval(sync_interval); //stops the interval
        sync_interval_running = false;
    };
    console.log("Sync Interval Stopped");
}
```

ok the thing is that, the second functions DOES NOT STOP, "update_seek_slider_position(gl_video.currentTime);"
it still goes one.

Does the js interval only accepts one function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following test is wrong so I guess the `clearInterval` function is never called:

```
if(sync_interval == true)
```

Replace it with:

```
if(sync_interval_running == true)
```

The `sync_interval` variable is returned by the `setInterval` function and is **not** a boolean value.

Same remark for your `start_sync` function. The test should be:

```
if(sync_interval_running == false)
```